# Pandas dataframe remove duplicates if duplicate count is more than 1 and matches a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have data which looks like this:

```
data = [['ABC','A','Good Value'], ['DEF','V','Good Value'], ['ABC','A','Unclear Value'], ['XYZ','B','Good Value'], ['LMN','N','Unclear Value'], ['JKL','M','Best Value'], ['ABC','A','Better Value'], ['JKL','M','Good Value']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Class', 'Value'])
```

| # | Name | Class | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | A | Good value |
| 2 | DEF | V | Good value |
| 3 | ABC | A | Unclear value |
| 4 | XYZ | B | Good value |
| 5 | LMN | N | Unclear value |
| 6 | JKL | M | Best value |
| 7 | ABC | A | Better value |
| 8 | JKL | M | Good value |

I am looking to remove duplicates on column ['Name', 'Class'] only when there are duplicates. If there is a single entry for a ['Name', 'Class'] combination then keep it. Also, when duplicates exist on columns ['Name', 'Class'], remove it only if the value is 'Unclear Value'.

So expected output is where the row #3 is removed and #1 and #7 are kept. Both #6 and #8 are kept as none of them is 'Unlcear value'. #5 is kept as it's the only row with Name LMN and Class N so even though it has Unclear value, it should be kept.

What I have so far is a priority list of all possible Values. Like ['Good value', 'Best Value', 'Better Value', 'Unclear Value'] where Unclear value is the last in the list. Then I have converted the Value column to Pandas Categorical

```
df.Value = pd.Categorical(df.Value, categories=['Good Value', 'Best Value', 'Better Value', 'Unclear Value'],ordered=True)
```

and then doing this:

```
df.sort_values('Value').groupby(['Name', 'Class']).first()
```

The problem I am running into with this approach is the one of #6 and #8 are getting dropped. Also, only one of the 3 rows #1, #3, #7 are kept whereas I would like only #3 to be dropped for it.

Another thing is, this priority list is actually just so that I get to keep a Good value over a Unclear Value. No such priority list is actually provided. I am defining this myself so I get to keep unclear at the lowest priority so that it may be dropped.  I would rather not have a priority list at all.

The only appraoch I can think of as of now is doing a group by and getting unique count of values. Then iterating over the groups where count is > 1 and for each such group, get rid of row where value is 'Unclear Value'. But I do not want to iterate over data so looking for a more sophisticated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with two masks:

```
# is the Name/Class combination duplicated?
m1 = df[['Name', 'Class']].duplicated(keep=False)
# is the Value "Unclear Value"?
m2 = df['Value'].eq('Unclear Value')

# drop if both conditions are met
out = df[~(m1&m2)]
```

Output:

```
  Name Class          Value
0  ABC     A     Good Value
1  DEF     V     Good Value
3  XYZ     B     Good Value
4  LMN     N  Unclear Value
5  JKL     M     Best Value
6  ABC     A   Better Value
7  JKL     M     Good Value
```

Intermediates:

```
  Name Class          Value     m1     m2  m1&m2  ~(m1&m2)
0  ABC     A     Good Value   True  False  False      True
1  DEF     V     Good Value  False  False  False      True
2  ABC     A  Unclear Value   True   True   True     False
3  XYZ     B     Good Value  False  False  False      True
4  LMN     N  Unclear Value  False   True  False      True
5  JKL     M     Best Value   True  False  False      True
6  ABC     A   Better Value   True  False  False      True
7  JKL     M     Good Value   True  False  False      True
```

Answer (score 0):

Same logic as @mozway with your idea of `Categorical`:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['Good Value', 'Best Value', 'Better Value',
                           'Unclear Value'], ordered=True)

cnt = (df.astype({'Value': cat}).sort_values('Value')
         .groupby(['Name', 'Class']).cumcount())

out = df[~(df['Value'].eq('Unclear Value') & cnt.gt(1))]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Name Class          Value  count
1  ABC     A     Good Value      0
2  DEF     V     Good Value      0
4  XYZ     B     Good Value      0
5  LMN     N  Unclear Value      0
6  JKL     M     Best Value      1
7  ABC     A   Better Value      1
8  JKL     M     Good Value      0
```